# Sequential invocation of asynchronous methods enforced by interface, Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following interface:

```
export interface Data {
    getText(): string;
}
```

Two classes implement mentioned interface:

```
export class LocalStorageData implements Data {
    public getText(): string {
        return localStorage.getItem('data');
    }
}

export class HttpData implements Data {
    public constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    public getText(): string {
        let text = '';

        this.http.get('http://server.com:3000/data').subscribe((response) => {
            text = response.toString();
        });

        return text;
    }
}
```

There is a class which uses `LocalStorageData` and `HttpData` classes:

```
export class Main {
    private http: Http;

    ...

    private getData(fromLocalStorage: boolean): Data {
        let data: Data;

        if (fromLocalStorage)
            data = new LocalStorageData();
        else
            data = new HttpData(this.http);

        return data;
    }

    public getText() {
        console.log(this.getData(true).getText());
        console.log(this.getData(false).getText());
    }
}
```

When `getText()` from `Main` class will be invoked, second console log will print an empty string because `get()` method from `Http` service is asynchronous.

How can I implement `Data` interface using asynchronous methods from `Http` service?

Answer (score -1):

change interface

from

```
export interface Data {
    getText(): string;
}
```

to

```
export interface Data {
    getText(): Observable<string>;
}
```

and return from local storage as

```
Observable.of(localStorage.getItem('data'))
```

and from HttpData as

```
export class HttpData implements Data {
    public constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    public getText(): Observable<string> {
        let text = '';

         return this.http.get('http://server.com:3000/data').map(res => res.json());

    }
}
```

and use this as follows

```
public getText() {
        this.getData(true).subscribe(test=> {
          console.log(text);
        })

        this.getData(false).subscribe(test=> {
          console.log(text);
        })
    }
```

Comment: I know that if I'll modify the interface and change `getText(): string` to `getText(): Observable<string>` it'll work. But unfortunately I cannot change the interface.

Comment: then all you can do is check if `data` is instance of `HttpData`, if yes then typecast and subscribe, else just get the value

Comment: This code is only an example. I wrote a library which provides the interface only, so the man who uses this library don't know what is under the hood - he expects that `getText()` will return string.